# How can I find out what version of network manager I can install on my ubuntu version 18+

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend

I am on ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and running network-manager 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4. I can see the latest version of network manager is about 1.23.
How can I find out what is the latest version of network manager I can install on my ubuntu 18.04.4?

When I use the ethernet cable if I am not interacting with ubuntu after a period the network locks and I have to reboot. I also have network problems when I sleep the pc and resume. I do not have any problems when using wifi.

Comment: I think a search with `apt search network-manager` would reveal the installable versions on our linux!

Comment: Ok that shows what installed but I want to install the latest network manager

Comment: If you want a newer version if Network Manager, then you should consider upgrading to a newer release of Ubuntu. NM is deeply integrated into the desktop. Wrong-version NM is NOT tested and may have unexpected results.